# Add class to div wrapped around custom post type based off posts category

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to inject a class into a div wrapped around a custom post type based off the category that post is attributed to.There will be three categories;

**ebook** (class name **cat1**)
**infographic** (class name **cat2**)
**case study** (class name **cat3**)

Here is my code so far to call the custom post type. Currently, the page displays all posts as the last category - case study (cat3).

```
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'resources', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            $post = $wp_query->post;

            if ( in_category('ebook', $post->ID) ) { ?>
                <div <?php body_class('tile scale-anm cat1 all end'); ?>>
                    <section class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns end">
                        <section class="grid">
                            <figure class="effect-sarah">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('img'); ?>" alt="img13"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Resource</h2>
                                    <p class="signika"><?php the_field('desc'); ?></p>
                                    <p class="bold"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></a>
                                </figcaption>           
                            </figure>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </div> 
            <?php
            } 


            elseif ( in_category('infographic', $post->ID) ) { ?>
                <div <?php body_class('tile scale-anm cat2 all end'); ?>>
                    <section class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns end">
                        <section class="grid">
                            <figure class="effect-sarah">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('img'); ?>" alt="img13"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Resource</h2>
                                    <p class="signika"><?php the_field('desc'); ?></p>
                                    <p class="bold"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></a>
                                </figcaption>           
                            </figure>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </div> 
            <?php
            } 


            elseif ( in_category('casestudy', $post->ID) ) { ?>
                <div <?php body_class('tile scale-anm cat3 all end'); ?>>
                    <section class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns end">
                        <section class="grid">
                            <figure class="effect-sarah">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('img'); ?>" alt="img13"/>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>Resource</h2>
                                    <p class="signika"><?php the_field('desc'); ?></p>
                                    <p class="bold"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></a>
                                </figcaption>           
                            </figure>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </div> 
            <?php
            }

            ?>          

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRY, Don't repeat yourself.  There are also some problems with your loop.

After using WP_Query, use `wp_reset_postdata()` not `wp_reset_query()`.

get rid of `$post = $wp_query->post;`, get the id from in the loop using `get_the_ID()`

Then we check the category and assign the class name to a variable `$catclass`, which we insert into the argument for `body_class()`, note the use of `"` instead of `'`

try this out:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'resources', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php
    $catclass = "";
    if (in_category('ebook', get_the_ID())) {
        $catclass="cat1";
    } else if(in_category('infographic', get_the_ID())) {
        $catclass="cat2";
    } else if(in_category('casestudy', get_the_ID())){
        $catclass="cat3";
    }
?>

    <div <?php body_class("tile scale-anm {$catclass} all end"); ?>>
        <section class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns end">
            <section class="grid">
                <figure class="effect-sarah">
                    <img src="<?php the_field('img'); ?>" alt="img13"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Resource</h2>
                        <p class="signika"><?php the_field('desc'); ?></p>
                        <p class="bold"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('btnText'); ?></a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div> 
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If you're really feeling frisky you can replace the `if/else` statements with:

```
switch(true){
    case in_category('ebook', get_the_ID()):
    $catclass = "cat1";
    break;
    case in_category('infographic', get_the_ID()):
    $catclass = "cat2";
    break;
    case in_category('casestudy', get_the_ID()):
    $catclass = "cat3";
    break;
    default:
    $catclass = "";
}
```

Comment: @WheatBreak Its so beautiful.... Thanks! that worked perfectly! I really appreciate it.  One more thing, I was using; data-rel="cat1" to filter items on the page, but i dont think this will work anymore. Is there a way to filter what shows on the page now using this new system?

Comment: That was vague... I have three buttons, one for each category. once clicked the post types not in the selected category hide. I used data-rel and it worked fine when it was just HTML. Not that i'm transferring over to the custom post types. I need to find a way to filter out items on button click. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand fully but if you're using jQuery you can just hide them like `jQuery(".cat1").hide()`

Comment: I'll look into the jQuery, thanks again @WheatBeak Suuuper helpful.